# jQuery handle php return

Tags: php, jquery, post

I want to have a jQuery script that recieves the return of an php script that made a database request with `$.post("script.php", args)` the request is started, but how to handle any answer?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ <= Have a look at the docs, especially the part about the "success callback".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really read these tutorials before jumping into something

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer to your question

jQuery post takes parameters like below

> jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [,
>   dataType] )

A typical jquery post request with certain parameters, expecting the results from a php file(test.php in this case) in XML format would be like the below

```
$.post("test.php",
 { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
 function(data) {
   process(data);
 }, 
 "xml"
);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("script.php", args, function(res) {
  // res is the response send to your from server
  // now do your stuff
});
```

Read about [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) methods and hope you will find solutions

Answer (score 1):

As many people suggested check with jQuery manual on possible usage of POST or AJAX calls,
here is my example of ajax calls:

```
$.post("server.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" }, function(data){
  console.log(data.name); //  John Doe
  console.log(data.time); //  2001-01-01 23:00:00
}, "json");
```

**server.php**

```
//do some processing and validation
$response = array('name' => 'John Doe', 'time'=> '2001-01-01 23:00:00');
print json_encode($response);
exit;
```